# Populating a dynamically added listbox from dynamically added combobox selection

Tags: vba, excel, controls

The userform has 3 columns, a combobox (list of vendors), and listbox (list of vendors' product / service) and a textbox with the price of the selected product / service.

[Example of menu (3rd column item not added)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPvik.png)

The user presses a button to add a row, which populates within a scrollable frame a new row of the 3 columns. My goal is to have the listbox's options change according to the selection in the combobox on that row.

I have a listener (see my previous post on combobox(number)_change() to see how this works) which is the following ...

```
Private Sub ControlHandlerCollection_ComboBoxChange(ComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox)

    MsgBox ComboBox.Name

End Sub
```

I wrote this to test if the change sub would work for ComboBox #87 for example. However, I don't know how to tell the same numbered listbox to change its list options according to the selection of ComboBox#

If I had a listener specifically for ComboBox1_Change() then I'd simply write the change for ListBox1 within it, but I'm writing this for a dynamic 'infinite' amount of ComboBoxes.

My current plan of attack would be to write within the sub in the code box above a block of code to parse the result of ComboBox.Name to grab the number as the result would be for example "ComboBox15" I could write a variable assigned to "ListBox" + (ComboBox.Name - "ComboBox") to call ListBox(number) however I'm not sure I can actually then call a variably based name of a listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK my father helped me come to this solution. It's a little static, but it works perfectly for what I need.

Had to edit the vendor data into multiple sheets and used the Define Name tool under Data to name the range. The listbox changes as per the selection of combobox.

```
Dim listBoxName As String
listBoxName = "myList" & ComboBox.Tag

Dim rangeName As String
rangeName = "company_1"

Select Case ComboBox.value
    Case "Company 1"
        rangeName = "company_1"
    Case "Company 2"
        rangeName = "company_2"
End Select

Dim listBox As Control
Set listBox = Me.Controls(listBoxName)
listBox.RowSource = rangeName
```

The above code was added to the private sub mentioned in the original thread.